# How to update embedded object in mongo db object

Tags: mongodb

Schema is like this

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId('5aaa41f96f69440f82ef45a7')
   "name":"test",
   "password" : "1234",
   "userInfo" : {
     "userName" : "usha",
     "organization" : [1,2]
}

}
```

If i am using a query like this then it is replacing userInfo object rather then updating it.

```
db.user.update({"_id":ObjectId('5aaa41f96f69440f82ef45a7')},{$set :{"userInfo":{"userName":"kanha"}}})
after using this query it is giving this result

{
   "_id":ObjectId('5aaa41f96f69440f82ef45a7')
   "name":"test",
   "password" : "1234",
   "userInfo" : {
     "userName" : "kanha"
}

}
```

It is deleting organizations from userInfo

expected Result

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId('5aaa41f96f69440f82ef45a7')
   "name":"test",
   "password" : "1234",
   "userInfo" : {
     "userName" : "kanha",
     "organization" : [1,2]
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
db.user.update({'_id':ObjectId('5aaa41f96f69440f82ef45a7')}, {$set:
  {
    'userInfo.$.userName': 'kanha'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.update({_id: '5aaa41f96f69440f82ef45a7'}, { '$set': {"userInfo.$.userName" : 'usha'})
```

it will also work in case of nested array.